How to update wordpress post date automatically when new content added by shortcode (dynamically content change)
i am using a wordpress plugin shortcode to add all list of recent articles of a particular category in a single post, and i am trying to make change my WP Post date and time when ever new content adding through shortcode like see in this picture.

i created this post 2 days ago but content in this post via shortcode adding like in every 10 minute, 20 min... Now i want to update this post Date and Time based on when Last Content (Post Article added through shortcode) in this cas like 10 mins ago.
I have this type multiple post, where I am going to add different-different category content and all post via different shortcode, I want to update these all post date and time according to their DOM content dynamically change or update through shortcode. so I need a universal code or way to achieve this on my whole wordpress website.
However, to get this for single one post, i tried by this php code to adding in my theme's function.php, But still it din't work.
    function update_post_date_from_shortcode($post_id) {
if (wp_is_post_autosave($post_id) || wp_is_post_revision($post_id)) {
    return;
}

// Check if the post contains the specific shortcode
$post_content = get_post_field('post_content', $post_id);
if (strpos($post_content, '**[my_shortcode]**') !== false) {
    // Update the post date to the current time
    wp_update_post(array(
        'ID' => $post_id,
        'post_date' => current_time('mysql', true),
        'post_date_gmt' => current_time('mysql', true),
    ));
}
}

Edit: i tried this one also, but it is still didn't worked:
function update_post_date_on_shortcode($atts) {
global $post;
$post->post_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$post->post_date_gmt = get_gmt_from_date($post->post_date);
wp_update_post($post);
}
add_shortcode("[my_shortcode]", 'update_post_date_on_shortcode');

Any one Expert know how i can achieve this? and what change i need to make in my this code?

Where is the content for this shortcode coming from? The same site or a third party? If the latter, is an API call made whenever a page with this shortcode on it is loaded, or is there a background service that periodically pulls in new content.

content for this shortcode coming from same site, from my own same wordpress blog latest post i am adding through the shortcode
my shortcode is like: [wmis posttype='post' poststatus='publish' postperpage='10' postorder='DESC' postorderby='date' category='6' columns='1' loadingoffset='1000' showimage='0' thumbsize='thumbnail' showtitle='1' showdate='1' showexcerpt='0' showreadmore='0' loadmorebutton='0' headingtype='h3'  titlesize='22' titlecolor='#337ab7']

It's difficult to understand your goal. In particular why the publish date of these posts should be updated every time this shortcode is rendered.
You appear to be using WP Masonry & Infinite Scroll, which doesn't seem to provide custom hooks to easily access each $post in the loop. Instead you might use the shortcode_atts_{$shortcode} core WordPress filter to perform some arbitrary action whenever your shortcode is rendered.
add_filter('shortcode_atts_wmis' function ($atts) {

    // Your logic goes here

    return $atts;

});

However global $post; in this case will refer to the post into which the  shortcode was placed (not the posts in your loop). You can try to reconstruct the list of posts from the shortcode attributes however given the number of available options for this particular shortcode, doing so would be unwieldly and difficult to maintain.

ya it's working but its updating date and time every time when i reload my post (that is getting content through this shortcode) that means render this shortcode, But But i want only update the post's date-time when some new post added in those particular category that I am listing in this shortcut.

@RakeshSuthar If you need to perform a task whenever a new post is created then you can use the wp_insert_post hook:
add_action('wp_insert_post', function ($post_id, $post, $update) { // do your thing }, 10, 3);
